# Trouble understanding this regular expression

Tags: javascript

```js
let name = "harry";
let text = "Harry is a suspicious character.";
let regexp = new RegExp("\\b(" + name + ")\\b", "gi");
console.log(text.replace(regexp, "_$1_"));
// → _Harry_ is a suspicious character.
```

This is the part of the code I do not get (" + name + "). Why not just (name)? Should (name) essentially be the same thing as ("harry")? Why does that not work? Why the + operator in there? Is it an attempt to concatenate?

Comment: It's not an "attempt to concatenate", it really is string concatenation.

Comment: `"\\b(" + name + ")\\b"` is not the same thing as `"\\b(name)\\b"`. Try printing both expression in the console.

Comment: Thanks Bergi I sort of figured it does not work, which is why I typed "Why does that not work?"

Answer (score 0):

The `RegExp()` is a constructor function. It's accepting string arguments. String is not a regex. You can use your console to understand it better, here:

[image]

See how before the constructor is executed, all actions in its arguments should execute first, including the concatenations.

See how the first argument of the RegExp function actually becomes what you'd expect? `+ name +` there is basically concatenation of a string variable to explicit inline strings. This may clarify concatenation for you: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat

Comment: Thanks, but this is the part I do not get. 

"there is basically concatenation of a string variable to explicit inline strings".

How does (" + "harry" + ") become (harry) the string literal? to me concatenation works like this "concatena" + "te" = "concatenate". a single " is not a string, so how does it concatenate to harry?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: Bergi, it's a screenshot of console. not code. Marco, single quote works similarly to a double quote. `let a = "qwe"; console.log(a + "rty");` gonna print "qwerty"